# Is it possible to set the chunk size when downloading from an Azure Datalake?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to download files from Azure Datalakes and would be like to be able to configure the chunk size as I see fit. Thing is, I cannot find any information on this in the documentation.

For Azure Blob Storage, you can set the chunk size (Although it's not exactly obvious from the documentation) like this:

```py
chunk_size = 1024 * 1024 * 10

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, max_chunk_get_size=chunk_size)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=self.container_name, blob=file_id)

stream = blob_client.download_blob()
with open(output_file_path, "wb") as output_file:
    for chunk in stream.chunks():
        # Do stuff with chunk your nice 10MB chunks
        output_file.write(chunk)
```

The same method of `DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, max_chunk_get_size=chunk_size)` however does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to set the chunk size when downloading from an Azure Datalake:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os

connection_string = "<connectionString>"
container_name = "<containerName>"
file_name = "<filePath>"
target_directory = "<targetDirectory>"  

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)  
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, file_name)

blob_properties = blob_client.get_blob_properties()
blob_size = blob_properties['size'] 
chunk_size = 100 * 1024 * 1024  # 100 MB
num_chunks = (blob_size + chunk_size - 1) // chunk_size
os.makedirs(target_directory, exist_ok=True)
   
for i in range(num_chunks):
    start_offset = i * chunk_size
    end_offset = min(start_offset + chunk_size, blob_size)
    chunk_file_name = os.path.join(target_directory, f"chunk_{i + 1}.dat")
    with open(chunk_file_name, "wb") as chunk_file:
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob(offset=start_offset, length=end_offset - start_offset)
        chunk_file.write(blob_data.readall())

print("Download and split complete.")
```

[image]

It downloaded the file in chunks according to the file size:

[image]

Comment: That was perfect, @Bhavani , thank you! I changed your code slightly to use the `DataLakeFileClient` instead of the `BlobClient`, and it works perfect for my situation.